# Overlay loading indicator before data and charts are loaded

Tags: chart.js

Is there a possibility to activate loading indicator (overlay) before date and charts are loaded? There is no info on this in documentation and also no event possibilities like `oninit` or `oncomplete`. 
Google also doesn't give any useful solutions. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The [`options.animation`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-configuration) lets you define how animation looks and how long it takes. Especially the `onProgress` and `onComplete` [animation callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-callbacks) may be useful in your case.

Please have a look at the following code sample: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/advanced/progress-bar.html

Comment: thx, except if I'm not wrong is that meant for chart animation. What I need is loading indicator before chart animation starts.